# Mistake during internship

Tags: professionalism, management, new-job, internship, manager

I've been an intern at a company for a little over a month and I have made a mistake. For context, this same mistake was once made by my manager when I first started and they pinned it on me, so this time around, it made it seem like I've made the same mistake again. My manager called me yelling over the phone and implicitly threatened to end my internship.

I started during COVID, so I didn't get the usual training and being in the same office as the manager, which made learning more difficult. I have started crying every day because of stress and the fear of making another mistake. This stress and fear have taken a toll on my health, but I need this internship for my school and I can't terminate the contract.

What should I do? How do I make up for it so that my manager isn't as harsh on me?

Comment: Jeez, anyone who would yell at an intern for making a mistake when they've only been on the job for a month has a real problem, and probably shouldn't be managing interns. Do you have any kind of mentor at the company?

Comment: My manager is my mentor. They don't even want me talking to others including HR, and since I'm working remote, my manager is the only person I talk to in the company

Comment: How long do you have left in your internship?

Comment: Have you spoken to your school about the situation?

Comment: Wow, there are so many red flags here I'm really not sure what to do.

Comment: @Gregory Currie I have 4.5 months left. I've spoken to my internship coordinator at uni and she told me to only complete the required internship duration duration graduate and then resign. She was shocked at the behavior of my manager but knows I don't have much choice since it's too late to start another internship

Comment: If by "yelling" you mean they actually raised their voice at you then this should be your indication that you do not want to work at this company after your internship ends.  I've been in the technology business for more than 40 years and I have never once been "yelled" at nor have I ever heard a manager yell at another employee even when they messed up badly.  Nobody is perfect and mistakes are simply a part of business.  You learn and you don't do that again.  But yelling?  That's simply unprofessional and should not ever be tolerated!

Comment: Yes, they definitely raised their voice and told me I have no added value to them while I've I've working overtime everyday since I've started, they also said I have no right to make mistakes since it's my final year of UNI. I've already made up my mind and I definitely will never work there no matter how high of a salary they offer. I'm so physically and mentally exhausted I just can't wait to leave and finally confront my manager about their behavior.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> For context, this same mistake was once made by my manager when I first started and they pinned it on me

Do you have any evidence that it was your manager that made this mistake? Like if you're a developer and you're using a version control system then you should be able to find the commit that your manager made that caused the first issue. Since that commit would be under his name and not yours that'd be your proof that it wasn't you.

If you have some proof I'd then present it to be your manager and be like:

> Just for the record, this is the first time ***I***  have made this mistake. The last time this mistake was made it was made by someone else, as evidenced by the following.

I wouldn't name your manager by name but presumably fault would be able to be determined by the evidence you presented.

Comment: My manager recalled their email the first time so I had no proof if was them who sent me the document containing a mistake, which I proceeded to forward because I thought it was all correct

Comment: @Douae831 - Was the document a Microsoft Word document? If so it might be possible to employee some forensic techniques to ascertain who made the change: https://www.vestigeltd.com/in-the-news/virtual-case-notes-piecing-together-truth-word-document/ . Recalls may also not be as fool proof as one might think: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-recall-an-email-after-it-has-been-read-by-the-recipient

Comment: What's the point of dredging up the past? An intern isn't going to be able to drive a forensic investigation against a manager to be able to attribute a mistake.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - it sounds like the past is why the OP is having a hard time. "_it made it seem like I've made the same mistake again_" the OP said. If people are operating under bad assumptions then it's best to correct those assumptions as opposed to just letting them fester. You call it dredging up the past, I call it setting the record straight. Especially in this context.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - and as for the OPs ability or lack their of to drive a forensic investigation...  Google can help. Maybe post on security.stackexchange.com too or something. Sure, the OP probably hasn't done it before. I haven't done it before. But just because neither of us have done it doesn't mean we are _incapable_ of doing it. Now is it worth the time and effort? That's something only the OP can answer.

Comment: @neubert, from OP's description of their manager's behavior, it seems more likely they are having a hard time because the manager is an abusive jerk. "Setting the record straight" is not likely to help matters.

Comment: @SethR - maybe. But if the evidence presented implicates the manager then there's a chance it could cause him to back off. Like what might go through his head when he sees this is "_oh shit, if this evidence is presented to **my** manager (or HR) then **I** could get in trouble. Best to play nice to minimize the odds of that happening_". I mean, ultimately, who knows which way it'd go, but it doesn't sound like the OP has much to lose either, if they're already being brought to the point of tears

Comment: My manager doesn't want me talking to anyone else in the company, not even HR. They say I should only talk to them and they'll get the message to the other person. I'm completely isolated and can't go into direct conflict with my manager because if i get kicked out of the internship, I'll fail my final year of UNI

Comment: @Douae831 - you've already said your manager "_implicitly threatened to end my internship_". I'd talk to your university and to HR. In spite of what your manager said. Your manager is likely trying to protect himself and hoping you're gullible enough to let him. HR knows how to be discrete. But before talking to HR I'd have as much documentation and proof as I possibly could. Maybe you won't need it but it's better to have it and not need it then it is to need it and not have it.

Answer (score 7):

> This stress and fear have taken a toll on my health but I need this internship for my school and I can't terminate the contract.

Brush it off. This is just a temporary placement for a specific purpose. Not worth getting upset over. You need to make a mental shift and discount the personalities.

Do the best you can and don't let people who will soon be irrelevant to you impact negatively on your mental health. That's the main thing to remember, this person and their petty tyranny are totally irrelevant.